# Interpreting the Google Maps API terms of service

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am not great at interpreting legalese, but from the Google Maps API [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), it seems that you cannot develop a non-browser application that connects to Static Maps API unless (a) the system does not have a browser or (b) you provide a link to the browser page of the map.

I see many mobile apps on Android which allow you to view Google Maps content, and do not link to the Google pages.  Android clearly DOES have a browser and a native mapping app.  How are these developers getting away with it?

Another rule from the terms: no caching/downloading of map data.

Some of these same mobile apps allow downloading large sets of tiles for use offline when in a remote area.  I've used them myself and they work great.  So again... how are the developers getting away with it?  Some of these apps are quite popular with hundreds of thousands of downloads.  Does Google just not care?

Or do I misunderstand the terms?  It is kind of confusing, since [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/):
it says

> This document is intended for website and mobile developers who want to include Google Static Maps API images within a webpage or mobile application

But most mobile platforms DO have browsers and native Google Maps apps, and the previously linked terms of service would seem to imply that developing mobile apps with this API is not cool.  So which is it?

Let's say I would like to:

(a) Develop a Java sourced mobile app which can connect to Google Static Maps API
(b) possibly download tiles from the API for local usage

The legality of (a) seems ambiguous based on the concerns mentioned above, while (b) seems clearly NOT legal, yet I see many successful mobile apps which do it.

And what if I for (a) it was a desktop app instead of a mobile app?

Comment: SO is for programming questions... this question seems to require an attorney well versed in software licenses and TOS.  This is way off-topic for SO.

Comment: The Google developers page says that this is the way to get official support from them, see this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/forum
EDIT: Although I do now see they have a separate contact link for non-code related questions.  My apologies.

Comment: I'm sure there are different TOS for business-license, also google may give extended permissions to somebody when they want to.